# Data is getting sorted on insertion into a non clustered indexed table

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I currently have a table in this design

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_all_DIVISION](
    [all_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [division_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [some_value] [tinyint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test_all_DIVISION] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [all_id] ASC,
    [division_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

where the all_id and division_id are foreign keys referring other tables
So while inserting data in this order of

```
all_id  division_id   some_value
94619   1153          24
94619   1133          25
94619   1002          22
94619   1156          23
```

its getting sorted based on division_id and inserted as below

```
all_id  division_id   some_value
94619   1002          22
94619   1133          25
94619   1153          24
94619   1156          23
```

Now i have changed that constraint to a non clustered one .
like this

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test_all_DIVISION]
DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_test_all_DIVISION]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test_all_DIVISION]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_test_all_DIVISION] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [all_id] ASC,
    [division_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Still the behaviour has not changed and the table is still sorting while doing an insert into the table and behaving like a clustered index.
So what am I doing wrong.Please help.

Comment: SQL tables are unordered sets of data. The **only** thing that governs sort order is the `ORDER BY` clause. It doesn't matter if you have or not have a clustered or not clustered index on the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is not sorted when inserting into a heap. Can you clarify why you need data inserted in a specific order. You can control the order when selecting the data by using an order by.

If you have to control insert order then you can add an IDENTITY column and cluster that.

-- Edit --

The only way to guarantee order of results is in the select statement. The clustered index will only affect the order in which the data is stored.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_all_DIVISION](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [all_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [division_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [some_value] [tinyint] NULL) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Then control order in the select statement.

```
SELECT
    [all_id],
    [division_id],
    [some_value]
FROM
    [dbo].[test_all_DIVISION]
ORDER BY
    [id];
```

Comment: Just to add, even if you cluster an IDENTITY column the only way to ensure data is selected in the correct order is with an ORDER BY.

Comment: The above table is used for storing a list which contains max 4 entries and need to be retrieved in the same order for displaying to the user or else it may confuse the user. You can see sorting happening on  the division_id column and I thought that the clustered index is the reason for the action and altered it but still the same behavior . So I even tried creating a similar schema with some dummy data and had a clustered index on the table and altered it. Now the behaviour got rectified and the data was inserted in the intended order. But that is not the case in this main table.

Comment: Thanks @Sean was able to resolve my problem with your suggestion .